# How do I store news articles with images inside in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, document

This might seem like a simple question for you, but I have spent the whole day on the internet searching for a good answer. What I am creating is a news web app with ReactJS as front-end and NodeJS Express backend and MongoDB. I am stuck on how do I store the articles with images inside the articles if required (very important). One option is to store them as documents but then how do I update it whenever required? (Help out this silly beginner, please)

Comment: Upload images to S3 or cloudinary and store that link in document in mongodb

Comment: Yes, that is one of the options but using a third party link in a document might lead to high loading time especially images. If there was an option to load articles and images at once as medium website does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have decided that it's the best thing to store images inside the database, I would base64 encode it and store it in the database, and when you retrieve it, decode and serve the image.

Without that assumption, though, putting images in the database makes your database grow larger, backups take longer, etc. And you get very few benefits - it's not like sorting or indexing pictures is a thing.